# angular chart not displaying in chrome browser

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, c3.js

I am using this directive for chart https://github.com/GraFiddle/angular-chart.
controller code is here
  .controller('myangularChart', function ($scope, $rootScope, $log, $state, chartService) {

```
(function initController() {
 chartService.getallstatus({})
 .then(function (response) {$scope.barChartData = response;

       $scope.options = {
         data:$scope.barChartData,
         dimensions: {
           y: {
             axis: 'y',
             type: 'bar',
             label: true,
             color: 'green',
             name: 'No. of students'
           },
           x: {
             axis: 'x',
             label: true,
             name: 'Status'
           }
         },
         chart:{
           axis: {
               y: {
                 max:50,
                 tick:{
                   format: d3.format('.0f')
                 },
                 label:{text:'No of students',
                   position: 'outer-middle'}

               }
             }

         }
       };
     })
  $scope.instance = null;
})();
```

})

bar  chart is not  displaying in  chrome browser but in Firefox browser  it is displaying .[chrome is displaying bar chart  shown in image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgTzG.png). In Firefox browser  it is working fine but not in chrome help me with this problem.

Comment: Can you create a plunker|jsfiddle?

Comment: any solution to this issue?

Comment: I have included $scope.options inside the $timeout(function(){ $scope.options = {........}  } , 1500);......I have 3 donut charts in my dashboard for 1st donut 1500, for 2nd 500, and 3rd 500 like that I gave delay Now its working fine, i feel its not the way to fix this issue, how to fix this issue without using the $timeout function??..One more thing I noticed is that mozilla firefox is working fine with and without the $timeout function.